# Simplify multiple nil checking in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

How should I write:

```
if @parent.child.grand_child.attribute.present?
  do_something
```

without cumbersome nil checkings to avoid exception:

```
if @parent.child.present? && @parent.child.grandchild.present? && @parent.child.grandchild.attribute.present?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing `nil` check? Then you don't need `present?`.

Comment: I thought it is equivalent to `if !@parent.child.nil? and !@parent.child.granchild.nil? ... `. Am I right?

Comment: No `present` is for checking whether it is either `nil` or `empty`. And you usually don't need `nil?` unless you want to distinguish `nil` from `false`.

Comment: At the very least you should pass this knowledge into the helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has `object.try(:method)`:

```
if @parent.try(:child).try(:grand_child).try(:attribute).present?
   do_something
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Object#andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/).

With it your code would look like this:

```
if @parent.andand.child.andand.grandchild.andand.attribute
```

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. I learn something new here. Just wonder if there's a more native way to say it.

Comment: @AdamNYC If you are expecting a Ruby native way, then you should not tag the question as `ruby-on-rails` as it has `try`, which is not Ruby native.

Comment: Thanks sawa. Either Ruby or Rails would be fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can slightly reduce it by assigning the intermediate values to some local variable:

```
if a = @parent.child and a = a.grandchild and a.attribute
```

Comment: I quite often use that too, usually with database queries for some reason, stuff like: `if (u = User[id]) && u.admin?`... but for more than two I use a library like ick or andand, or it can start to look messy. +1 for a really useful tip.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, you could use a fold:

```
[:child, :grandchild, :attribute].reduce(@parent){|mem,x| mem = mem.nil? ? mem : mem.send(x) }
```

but using andand is probably better, or [ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/), which I like a lot and has methods like `try` and `maybe`.

Comment: I was going to mention Ick, but I thought that it's an overkill in this case :-)

Comment: quite probably, but it is beautiful to behold (especially `let`) :-)

Comment: Thanks Iain and Sergio. Ick is also new for me, and it seems that I got a better answer than I asked for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute you are checking is always the same, create a method in @parent.

```
def attribute_present?
  @parent.child.present? && @parent.child.grandchild.present? && @parent.child.grandchild.attribute.present?
```

end

Alternatively, create `has_many :through` relationship so that `@parent` can get to `grandchild` so that you can use :

```
@parent.grandchild.try(:attribute).try(:present?)
```

Note: `present?` is not just for nil, it also checks for blank values, `''`. You can just do `@parent.grandchild.attribute` if it's just nil checking

Answer (score 0):

You coult just catch the exception:

```
begin
  do something with parent.child.grand_child.attribute
rescue NoMethodError => e
  do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it using a `delegate` method as a result you'll have sth like

```
@parent.child_grand_child_attribute.present?
```

Comment: http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/ an article with more info

Answer (score 0):

Hi Think you can use a flag variable here with rescue option

```
flag = @parent.child.grand_child.attribute.present? rescue false

if flag
do_something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Optional = Struct.new(:value) do
  def and_then(&block)
    if value.nil?
      Optional.new(nil)
    else
      block.call(value)
    end
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    and_then do |value|
      Optional.new(value.public_send(*args, &block))
    end
  end
end
```

Your check would become:

```
if Optional.new(@parent).child.grand_child.attribute.present?
  do_something
```

Source: http://codon.com/refactoring-ruby-with-monads

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are old, so I thought I should share more modern options.

If you are getting an association that might not exist:

```
@parent&.child&.grand_child&.attribute
```

if you are reaching into a hash for a key that might not exist:

```
hash = {
 parent_key: {
   some_other_key: 'a value of some sort'
 },
 different_parent_key: {
   child_key: {
     grand_child: {
       attribute: 'thing'
     }
   }
 }
}
hash.dig(:parent_key, :child_key, :grandchild_key)
```

Either of these will gracefully return nil if child, grandchild, or attribute don't exist