# Is there an equivalent null prevention on chained attributes of groovy in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Groovy:

if there`s my_object -> access 'name' and capitalize

```
my_object?.name?.capitalize()
```

What is the equivalent for ruby to avoid a nil object to access attributes with this facility?

Thanks

Comment: this is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721949/simplify-multiple-nil-checking-in-rails/8722096#8722096

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works in Rails:

```
my_object.try(:name).try(:capitalize)
```

If you want it to work in Ruby you have to extend `Object` like this:

```
class Object
  ##
  #   @person ? @person.name : nil
  # vs
  #   @person.try(:name)
  def try(method)
    send method if respond_to? method
  end
end
```

[Source](http://ozmm.org/posts/try.html)

In [Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) it's implemented like this:

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      __send__(*a, &b)
    end
  end
end

class NilClass
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: notably, this is different to `ActiveSupport`'s `Object#try`. `ActiveSupport`'s implementation is basically just `send`, except `nil.try` always returns `nil`

Comment: Thanks @MatthewRudy. This is better since it also accepts blocks and parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) provides this functionality.

```
my_object.andand.name.andand.capitalize()
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you mean you want to avoid a nil error if my_object is nil. Try :

```
my_object?.name?.capitalize() unless my_object.nil?
```

Ruby will do the nil check first and only then try to access the attribute if my_object isn't a null.

Dave

Comment: I think the point of the question is how to make it work without `unless` or `if`.

Comment: I get `undefined method 'my_object?'` if `my_object` is defined.

Comment: @undur_gongor That's because there's no such thing as `?.` in Ruby.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Or, because the question mark is part of the identifier `my_object?`.

Comment: @undur_gongor Correct; there's no `?.` in Ruby.

Comment: This also won't deal with `name` being `nil`, btw, which I think is part of the OP's intent.