# Does Ruby have syntax for safe navigation operator of nil values, like in Groovy?

Tags: ruby, null, operators

In Groovy, there is a nice syntax for working with null values.

For example, I can do an if statement:

```
if (obj1?.obj2?.value) {

}
```

This will not throw a NullPointerException even if obj1 is null (it will evaluate to false).

This is something that's very convenient, so wondering if there is a Ruby equivalent I missed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805582/is-there-an-equivalent-null-prevention-on-chained-attributes-of-groovy-in-ruby

Comment: thanks!  Also found the andand gem just now that tries to introduce this to ruby through a method:  http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/01/objectandand-objectme-in-ruby.html

Comment: Not yet in a stable release, but the development branch of Ruby now has the `.?` operator. See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email#note-12

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a rails app there is `Object#try`

So you can do

```
obj1.try(:obj2).try(:value)
```

or with a block (as said on comments bellow)

```
obj.try {|obj| obj.value}
```

**UPDATE**

In ruby 2.3 there is operator for this:

```
obj&.value&.foo
```

Which is the same as `obj && obj.value && obj.value.foo`

Comment: Or alternately: `obj.try {|obj| obj.value}` - block mode often makes more visual sense IMHO.

Comment: This block syntax makes the most sense when you want to do something with the value like call a method on it.

Comment: A common pattern to tackle this kind of problem are [null objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/20907555103/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object).

Comment: Note that [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) is a part of the [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) gem, which can also be used outside of Rails.

Comment: *"Which is the same as"*... This is not true when `obj` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks Jesse for the heads up

Comment: @Ismael I see this equivalency stated in every resource I can find about the new operator. I posted a new question regarding this misinformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602054/what-is-the-closest-equivalent-to-rubys-safe-navigation-operator

Comment: `[20] pry(main)> @asd.try(:asd)
NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @akostadinov try is only available with ActiveSupport (part of Ruby on Rails)

Answer (score 7):

[This has been added](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) to Ruby 2.3.

The syntax is `obj1&.meth1&.meth2`.

Answer (score 2):

`try` was the only standard way to do this before Ruby 2.3. With Ruby 2.3 you can do:

```
if obj1&.obj2&.value

end
```

Also, if you have a hash structure, you can use the `_.` operator with [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie):

```
require 'hashie'
myhash = Hashie::Mash.new({foo: {bar: "blah" }})

myhash.foo.bar
=> "blah"    

myhash.foo?
=> true

# use "underscore dot" for multi-level testing
myhash.foo_.bar?
=> true
myhash.foo_.huh_.what?
=> false
```

Comment: So, try *was* the only way to do this when I answered the quesiton. The &. notation was just added with Ruby 2.3. The downvote wasn't really necessary, a comment or edit would have been appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if your downvote was related, but I just made an edit because you were using JavaScript syntax for your if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.3 will have support for the safe navigation operator:

```
obj1&.obj2&.value
```

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/11/11/ruby-2-3-0-preview1-released/