# Nil dereference may occur in ternary operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I write 2 method, one with ternary operator and one with if..else..end.

```
def test_a()
  return (a.blank? or a.body.blank?) ? {} : a.body
end

def test_b()
  if a.blank? or a.body.blank?
    return {}
  else
    return a.body
  end
end
```

I think both of them seem to be the same.

But in RubyMine it show warning at `a.body` of ternary :

> Nil dereference may occur ruby in ternary operator

[image]

Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: First of all, `||` is preferred over `or` due to precedence concerns.

But other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: There is no method `blank?` in Ruby in the first place.

Comment: Also, in both methods the local variable `a` is not ever defined.

Comment: "Am I using the wrong syntax?" – No. If you were using wrong syntax, you would get a `SyntaxError`. A `nil` dereference clearly is not a syntactic issue, it is a semantic one. Plus, this is not an error, just a warning.

Comment: RubyMine cannot parse your condition and concludes that `a` might be `nil` in either case, hence the warning. Using `||` instead of `or` and removing the parentheses should fix it.

Comment: My *guess* without knowing the internals of RubyMine would be that the static analyzer gets confused in one snippet but not in the other. Ruby is notoriously hard to analyze statically, so oddities, false positives, and false negatives, are to be expected.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Sorry, my bad. It's Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about rubymine itself, but the

> [nil dereference may occur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164191/1184717)

notification happens since you access `a.body.blank?` before you check whether `body` is nil or not. some avoid this by using `a.body && a.body.blank?`. in ruby 2.3 there is a short syntax for this `a.body&.blank?`

Comment: The warning highlights `a.body`, not `a.body.blank?`

Answer (score 1):

As @Stefan's answer : Using || instead of or and ...

> ...removing the parentheses should fix it

```
def test_a
  a.blank? || a.body.blank? ? {} : a.body
end
```

I think this is quick right answer in my case. Tested in RubyMine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write that expression as follows:

```
a&.body.presence || {}
```

- If `a` is `nil` it will return `{}`.
- If `a.body` is `nil` it will also return `{}`
- If `a.body` is blank it will also return `{}`
- If `a.body` is present, it will return `a.body`