# Ruby syntactic sugar for chains of (!obj.nil?)

Tags: ruby, groovy, null, syntactic-sugar, null-pointer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash)
>   [Is there an equivalent null prevention on chained attributes of groovy in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805582/is-there-an-equivalent-null-prevention-on-chained-attributes-of-groovy-in-ruby)

Is there any syntactic sugar, in Ruby, that help avoiding "undefined method `xx' for nil:NilClass" without writing this?

```
if !something.nil? && !something.very.nil? && !something.very.long.nil? && !something.very.long.to.nil? then
   if something.very.long.to.write != 0 then
    ...
   end
end
```

in Groovy I'll do this

```
if(something?.very?.loong?.to?.write != 0)
```

Is there an equivalent syntax for Ruby?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164004/does-ruby-have-syntax-for-safe-navigation-operator-of-nil-values-like-in-groovy from 4 days ago

Comment: Thanks, it was hard to search in the tons of Ruby questions...

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash. In a nutshell: `andand` or `maybe` (ick).

Answer (score 1):

It's a duplicate question, but I can't find that for the moment. My way is:

```
if a = something and a = a.very and a = a.long and a = a.to
  if a = a.write
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sweet enough, I need more sugar ;-) Groovy 1 : Ruby 0

Comment: ouch, this "a" may get real dizzy with some many value destructive changes :-p

Comment: @tokland If a distructive operation appears within the sequence, you can take `a.dup` to continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      __send__(*a, &b)
    end
  end
end

class NillClass
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Then in your case

```
if result = something.try(:very).try(:long).try(:to).try(:write)
  if result != 0
  end
end
```