# Ruby on rails, multiple check for nil attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to check multiple attributes for nil, I've found this post [simplify...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721949/simplify-multiple-nil-checking-in-rails) but I'm not getting the results I want. I have a user whom I want to update their profile if needed. This user however has all the data I want.

```
  @user.try(:age_id).nil?
    #returns false
  @user.try(:customer).nil?
    #returns false
  @user.try(:country).nil? 
    #returns false

  @user.try(:age_id).try(:customer).try(:country).nil?
    #returns true
```

Why is it responding with true here when all the other single instances of tries responds with false?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are chaining the `.try()`, which fails after the `try(:age_id)`:

- It tries to call `age_id` on the `@user` object
- if `@user.nil?` # => returns `nil`
- if `@user.age_id != nil` # => returns a `Fixnum`
- Then you call the method `try(:customer)` on a Fixnum which obviously fails # => returns `nil`

etc.

An example from the IRB console:

```
1.9.3p448 :049 > nil.try(:nothing).try(:whatever).try(:try_this_also).nil?
 => true
```

---

If you want to test that all of these attributes are not nil, use this:

```
if @user.present?
  if @user.age_id.presence && @user.customer.presence && @user.country.presence
    # they are all present (!= nil)
  else
    # there is at least one attribute missing
  end
end
```

Comment: Another option is `%w( age_id customer country ).all? { |attr| @user[attr].present? }`